# How to detect if a func. is a constexpr? and mark other func. constexpr depending on it?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

Assuming i have some function template f1:

```
template<typename f2>
int f1(int i, int j) noexcept {
  return i + j + f2(i, j);
}
```

is there way to determine if `f2(i, j)` can be a `constexpr`. (no matter it is a func. or a functor) and so mark `f1<f2>` as a `constexpr` too?

I am thinking of using SFINAE here some how, but didn't find how to detect `constexpr` using [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits)

Comment: I'm also interested in this. Sometimes, you want to overload an algorithm depending on `constexpr`ness, because one implementation of the algorithm is `constexpr`able but another one is faster.

Comment: Also, side note but: `throw()` is deprecated, use `noexcept` if you can (or remove it from your example, it's not really relevant to your problem)

Comment: @KABoissonneault, thank you, using 'throw()' is just a habit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can mark `f1` as `constexpr`.

```
template<typename f2>
constexpr int f1(int i, int j) noexcept {
  return i + j + f2(i, j);
}
```

The template function `f1` would be `constexpr` iif `f2` is.

if `f2` is not, you will get error only when you use `f1` in a constant compile time expression.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de6d808d764db22d)

Comment: Good answer, but I think those parentheses after `noexcept` are invalid

Comment: @KABoissonneault: typo fixed.

Comment: @AmaboCarab you didn't use a function *template* in your example. I think that's crucial for this to work.

Comment: @user2079303, yep, you right, i tested it just addding 'template' and now its work: https://ideone.com/ynHeGV. Magic!

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you show to call `f1`? I believe `typename f2` says it's a type type template parameter therefore you cannot just use it like it's in your code right?

Comment: @Patryk: Indeed, it is not the normal way to use it I would use `f2{}(i, j)`. But it is possible: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de6d808d764db22d)

Comment: @Jarod42 But you're creating structs with `operator int()`. How would you use this very template with function (pointer)?

Comment: @Jarod42 That is totally different than code in your example. I am concerned about usage of `f1` template. How would you pass a function pointer to it?

Comment: @Patryk i think we can use a _pointer to function_ type as _f2_, something like `int(*p)(int, int)`, through i'am not sure it is possible to call a func. by pointer in a `costexpr` function.

Comment: @Patryk: something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc31bb64a6b441f2)

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok now I get it that I missed the `&` operator

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to check whether a function (e.g., `foo`) is `constexpr` is to assign its return value to a `constexpr` as below:

```
  constexpr auto i = foo();
```

if the returned value is not `constexpr` compilation will fail.

If you want a SFINAE test to check whether a function (e.g., `foo`) is `constexpr` you could use the [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) type trait:

```
std::integral_constant<int, foo()>::value
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c9af7574811c453)

Comment: That doesn't seem any SFINAE friendly

Comment: @KABoissonneault Hope now you're covered.

Comment: With your edit, can you show an example of how this could be used, for example, to overload a function? Because as far as I know, if you send a non-`constexpr` value to a template, it will just fail to compile, not "SFINAE".

Comment: @KABoissonneault isn't it better to leave this as an exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: @101010 thank you for a type traits example, i think it is usefull too!

Comment: @101010 : I don't think it's possible to make a proper SFINAE trait for non-nullary callables. Or in any case, [_I_ wasn't able to do it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05965219c9772f91). ;-]

Answer (score 0):

So, finally, using **Jarod42** hint, i'l write and tested [this example](https://ideone.com/ynHeGV):

```
#include <string>
std::string S = "123567876";

constexpr size_t p() noexcept {
  return 10U;
}

template<const size_t = size_t()>
constexpr size_t f(size_t i, size_t j) noexcept {
  return std::move(i + j + S.size() + p());
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
  // static constexpr const auto v = f<>(1U, 2U); // error!
  std::cout << f(1U, 2U) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

now it's work correctly, i tested it using GCC online complier with both C++11 and C+14.

---

You can proof it will be really constexpr if possible by removing '+ S.size()':

```
...
  return std::move(i + j + p());
...
```

and uncommenting constexpr value:

```
...
  static constexpr const auto v = f(1U, 2U);
  std::cout << v << "\n";
...
```

see [here](https://ideone.com/BW7E8q).

---

P. S. Thank you guys!

Comment: Why are you calling `std::move` on fundamental data? `size_t` is trivially constructible already, you don't get anything. Also I don't see what your template is actually doing anymore

Comment: @KABoissonneault i call it to just test if it would complie. I need it as i am using it in a signifficantly more complicated example, i called it [Execute Member Function If It Is Present idiom](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1029697/Execute-Member-Function-If-It-Is-Present), better see [latest version](https://github.com/RussianEmpire/GenericCPPLib/blob/master/SRC/FuncUtils.h) in the repository. Now i'am upgrading it to make it conditionally use `constexpr`.

Comment: ["If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor when considered as a non-template function or constructor, the template is ill-formed; no diagnostic required."](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6)

Comment: @T.C., well, thank you, this is interesting anf frustrating a bit, still GCC compile it OK, at least in the debug mode.

Comment: @T.C., also i see 'c++draft' in the link, is it a draft? Is it a C++11/14/17 draft?